# Google CardDAV API 403 Error

Tags: google-api, http-status-code-403, google-api-client, carddav

I've been trying to use Google's CardDAV APIs (and I've successfully gotten CalDAV access working).  Unfortunately, I keep getting a 403 error when trying to discover the user's current-user-principal.  FWIW, I have gone to Google's Developer Console and set up client information and it seems to work perfectly fine for CalDAV access.

Here is a snippet of the HTTP traffic for CardDAV:

```
PROPFIND https://www.googleapis.com:443/.well-known/carddav/
Depth: 0
Content-Type: text/xml
Brief: T
Authorization: Bearer ya29.1.AADtN_UD1CVKpIQPsyB4HzoKVxt4L5kPFXU3GucMTfJmJj9t0pzZqX1i3Xx748Y
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<x0:propfind xmlns:x0="DAV:">
  <x0:prop>
    <x0:current-user-principal />
    <x0:principal-URL />
    <x0:resourcetype />
  </x0:prop>
</x0:propfind>

vvvvvvvvvvvv

HTTP PROPFIND Status(403) Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
 <error>
  <domain>GData</domain>
  <code>insufficientPermissions</code>
  <internalReason>Insufficient Permission</internalReason>
 </error>
</errors>
```

If anyone has some insight as to why this might be happening, it would be greatly appreciated.

Red

Answer (score 0):

You need to request access for Google Carddav API, i.e. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/carddav

I fear that still might not be enough rights, because even with that permission (and also the permission for https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts) I get empty reports for my addressbook. That's very strange. Even after putting a contact with my client.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Actually, I had already requested access through the developer's dashboard, by evidence of the OAuth2 bearer token.  So there seems to be another cause of the 403 error as you eluded.

Comment: Yes, but for what domains? You need to request access for the right domains to get carddav working... For me, when I requested access to the domain "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/carddav", I would not get 403 errors anymore. But listings would still be empty. Probably @davef has the right hind here.

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing around with this today and succeeded just now.
I am using two oauth scopes

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/carddav

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds

I was getting a 403 when just using the second one.
I then do a depth 1 `propfind` on `getetag` and then a `multiget` to get the `vcards`.
The response is super speedy.

p.s. With the URL you are using you will also get an http-redirect

Comment: With "multiget", do you mean REPORT addressbook-multiget? I'm able to do any PROPFIND, but REPORT addressbook-multiget fails with 400 Bad request. have you been able to run this against Google's CardDAV?